# Sent a value from a tJava component to a tMap

Tags: talend

I want to retrieve the value of a tJava component in a tMap component.

I made my program, and returns a row.ma_value

I create my schema as built-in.

I try to connect it to my tMap component but it doesn't give me any connection.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`tJava` is not to be used as a flow component. Use `tJavaRow` instead to pass rows to the next component. With `tJavaRow` you get 2 variables: `input_row` to access input flow columns, and `output_row` to access outgoing flow columns.

If you need `tJavaRow` to be the first component of the subjob, use `tJavaFlex` instead.

Comment: knowing that I have a tlibraryload (.jar) as input.

Comment: What do you mean tLibraryLoad as input ? tLibraryLoad is used to load a jar, but not as input.. could you please add a screenshot of your job ?

Comment: if i use tjavarow , i can't connect hem with tlibraryload .

Comment: Ok I see; in that case use tJavaFlex (updated my answer)

Comment: I want to get the value of the attributes generated by an.jar that I got by tLibraryLoad, then do the mapping to load the data into a database.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; does your jar contain a java program that you want to call in tJava ? If so, you can access it by calling MyClass.myMethod() in a tJavaFlex

Comment: I want to get toto.txt from the url as parameter to replace the file location in tJavaFLex.

My code initial in tJavaFlex today is:

 Bak bak = BakReader.getInstance().read("D:\test2.bak", "utf-8");
my url : 

http://localhost:8088/references?fileName=toto.txt.
What I want is: 

Bak bak = BakReader.getInstance().read("D:\toto.txt, "utf-8");
Thank you